# Websocket - на локалке работает, а на хостинге нет

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

ws websocket :
делал все как на видео - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DKOaL94VyFY&ab_channel=CodeDojo
Поменял под сервер в файлах:

server.js:

```
const server = new WebSocket.Server({port:433});
```

//поменял порт с 3000 на 433 думаю это не решает
//пробовал и 3000

в app.js на клиенте:

```
const ws = new WebSocket('ws://http://sanq.tech:433')
```

///http://sanq.tech вместо localhost поменял путь к своему домену с хостом и портом

пишет

app.js:22 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'WebSocket': Still in CONNECTING state.
at HTMLFormElement. (http://sanq.tech/app.js:22:4)
(anonymous) @ app.js:22
app.js:7 WebSocket connection to 'ws://http//sanq.tech:433' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Если же использовать localhost с портом 3000 все работает на локалке, а как же на хостинге натроить правильно? Спасибо большое

Comment: предполагаю, что адрес на клиенте надо заменить с ws://http\://sanq.tech:433 на ws://sanq.tech:433 (или ws://sanq.tech или wss//sanq.tech)

Comment: если вы используете протокол websocket (ws), то нет смысла указывать еще и протокол http. Если порт 433, то, наверно, нужно использовать secure websocket (wss)